# Java an Array of Objects within an Array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm trying to create an array of objects that looks like object1[].object2[]. However, my code doesn't appear to work, so where did I go wrong in my code?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int evolve = 1;
        int rows = 2;


        Evolution[] a = new Evolution[evolve];
        for(int i=0; i<evolve; i++){
            a[i] = new Evolution();

            Evolution.Node[] b = a[i].new Node[rows];
        }

    }
}

public class Evolution{
    double fitness;
    public class Node{
        double value = 900; //900 was a test value
    }
    public class Synapsis extends Node{
        double weight;
        double input;
        double output;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't appear to work"? Are you getting an error? Are you getting the wrong output. Please add more detail to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the syntax of inner class instantiation with array instantiation. Your array creation should look like this:

```
Evolution.Node[] b = new Evolution.Node[rows];
```

If you want to *populate* the array, then you'll need something like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    b[j] = a[i].new Node();
}
```

Comment: `a[i].new Node()` is valid Java syntax?

Comment: @TotZam [Yup.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) Looks funny, I know.

Comment: I rarely use nested classes. I guess that is why I've never seen that syntax before. Just learnt something new. Thanks.

Comment: @TotZam Inner classes are commonly used for objects tied to some outer instance, `Iterator` being a classic example. But it's rare to see this syntax because the inner object is usually constructed within the outer class, so it's just `new Inner()`.

Comment: it looks ugly though